# ReactJS, find elements by classname in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a React component. Some elements will be inserted through the children. Some of these elements will have a specific classname.
How can I get a list of these DOM nodes in my outermost Component?

```
<MyComponent>
  <div classname="snap"/>
  <p></p>
  <div classname="snap"/>
  <p></p>
  <div classname="snap"/>
</MyComponent>
```

What I want to know is how many elements with the classname "snap" are inserted in my component.

Comment: you want to know how many snaps are in MyComponent from inside MyComponent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`. Even though the documentation encourage using **ref**, let's see how it works:

**findDOMNode()**

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)
```

> If this component has been mounted into the DOM, this returns the
>   corresponding native browser DOM element. This method is useful for
>   reading values out of the DOM, such as form field values and
>   performing DOM measurements. In most cases, you can attach a ref to
>   the DOM node and avoid using findDOMNode at all.
>
> When a component renders to null or false, findDOMNode returns null.
>   When a component renders to a string, findDOMNode returns a text DOM
>   node containing that value. As of React 16, a component may return a
>   fragment with multiple children, in which case findDOMNode will return
>   the DOM node corresponding to the first non-empty child.

---

> **Note:** findDOMNode is an escape hatch used to access the underlying DOM
>   node. In most cases, use of this escape hatch is discouraged because
>   it pierces the component abstraction. findDOMNode only works on
>   mounted components (that is, components that have been placed in the
>   DOM). If you try to call this on a component that has not been mounted
>   yet (like calling findDOMNode() in render() on a component that has
>   yet to be created) an exception will be thrown. findDOMNode cannot be
>   used on functional components.

Also let's look at the ref, which is recommended:

#### Adding a Ref to a Class Component

> When the ref attribute is used on a custom component declared as a
>   class, the ref callback receives the mounted instance of the component
>   as its argument. For example, if we wanted to wrap the CustomTextInput
>   above to simulate it being clicked immediately after mounting:

```
class AutoFocusTextInput extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.textInput.focusTextInput();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <CustomTextInput
          ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
      );
    }
}
```

> Note that this only works if CustomTextInput is declared as a class:

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve it, via `findDOMNode` of `react-dom`, like below:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(<instance-of-outermost-component>).getElementsByClassName('snap') // Returns the elements
```

If you need the count,

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(<instance-of-outermost-component>).getElementsByClassName('snap').length
```

Comment: I got error like "Uncaught Error: Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode."

Comment: what is instance-of-outermost-component?

Comment: @SagarKodte - In this example, it is `<MyComponent>`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where `document.getElementsByClassName` was not returning what I needed. I found that using `document.querySelectorAll` did the trick. In terms of the code in question:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(["classname=snap"])
const length = elements.length
```

Why does this work? As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector, `document.querySelector` will return the first element within the document that matches the specified selector. Therefore, `document.querySelectorAll` will return all elements within the document that matches the specified selector.

I know this post is quite old but hopefully the above can help someone in a similar position to me. I came to the conclusion that `document.getElementsByClassName` probably doesn't work with React because according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName this is applicable to elements that have a `class` as opposed to a `className`.

Answer (score 2):

Yoy can also use `this.props.children` to get number of child nodes with given class:

```
let snapCount = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).filter((item) => item.props.className === 'snap').length;
```