# React | How to get length of divs by id/class?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to find the length of child element divs

```
<div className="intentContainer">
      <div className="intent">
      </div>
      <div className="intent">
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code. Need to find no of 'intent' elements

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.intentContainer > .intent').length` use this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS, find elements by classname in a React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666140/reactjs-find-elements-by-classname-in-a-react-component)

Comment: Please check demo to here https://jsfiddle.net/santoshshinde2012/Lfqcpc3f/8/ and check the following answer in detail

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`, even-though the documentation encourages using `ref`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/santoshshinde2012/Lfqcpc3f/8/)

You need to put `ref` on parent node.

```
<div ref="intentContainer" className="intentContainer"></div>
```

Use the following code in our `componentDidMount` method.

```
 componentDidMount(){

    // get this intentContainer using ref (Its your parent)
    var intentContainer = this.refs.intentContainer;

    // this will return the count of all childrens 
    var childrenCount = this.refs.intentContainer.children.length;

    // get the count by particular class name from parent dom
    var countByClass = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(intentContainer).getElementsByClassName('intent').length;

  }
```

And your render method like as follows,

```
   render() {
      return (
        <div ref="intentContainer" className="intentContainer">
           <div className="intent">
           </div>
           <div className="intent">
           </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

For more help please check to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666140/reactjs-find-elements-by-classname-in-a-react-component) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Hoeps this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`callback ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

```
ref={(ele) => this.myEle = ele
```

put `callback ref` on parent node which length or child count you want.

```
return (<div style={styles} ref={(ele) => this.myEle = ele}>
        <div >Hello World</div>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
     </div>);
```

Use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) or [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) life cycle to get the length.

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log(this.myEle.children.length); //2
}
```

Working [`React#codesandbox demo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/0y63zo9510)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class SampleComponent extends Component {
    intentCount(){
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.intent').length)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="intentContainer">
                <div className="intent">
                </div>
                <div className="intent">
                </div>
                <div className="intent">
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.intentCount}>Intent Count</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This should work :) ..