# Calling a function inside render function - ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok so I am making a "buzzfeed" quiz generator and I am having an issue with a piece of my form. So for each question made there are two different parts, a "Question" and the "Answers". There will always be 4 answers but I want to keep track of which Answers are checked later so I would like to give each answer a unique id `"question" + questionNum + "Answer" + answerNum` or `"question" + questionNum + "Answer" + i` So I made this `answersGenerator` function that is supposed to give me 4 unique answer choice fill ins for the user to input answers for that specific questions (right now it says something about terms and conditions - ignore that I ad just left it like that for now because I was following a tutorial). Here is all my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

var questionNum = 1;
var answerNum = 1;

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quizTitle: "",
      author: "",
      question: "",
      terms: false,
      test: "",
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>
          <p className="App-intro">
            To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="columns">
            <div className="formDiv">
              <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="field">
                  <label className="label">Give your quiz a title.</label>
                  <div className="control">
                    <input
                      className="input"
                      type="text"
                      name="quizTitle"
                      value={this.state.quizTitle}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                  <label className="label">Who's the Author?</label>
                  <div className="control">
                    <input
                      className="input"
                      type="text"
                      name="author"
                      value={this.state.author}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="questions" id="questions">
                  <div className="question" id={'questionGroup' + questionNum}>
                    <div className="field">
                      <label className="label" id={'question' + questionNum}>Question {questionNum}</label>
                      <div className="control">
                        <input
                          className="input"
                          type="text"
                          name='question'
                          value={this.state.question}
                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="answersDiv">
                    <label className="label">Answers</label>
                      <div className="field">
                        <div className="control">
                          <label className="checkbox">
                              {this.answersGenerator()}
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="field">
                  <div className="endButtons">
                    <button id="addQuestionButton"
                      onClick={addQuestion}>Add Question</button>
                    <input
                      type="submit"
                      value="Submit"
                      id="submitButton"
                      className="button is-primary"
                    />
                  </div>
              </div>
              </form>
          </div>

            <div className="column is-3">
              <pre>
                <code>
                  <p>Quiz Title: {this.state.quizTitle}</p>
                  <p>Author: {this.state.author}</p>
                  <p>Question: {this.state.question}</p>
                  <p>Terms and Condition: {this.state.terms}</p>
                  <p>Do you test?: {this.state.test}</p>
                </code>
              </pre>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function answersGenerator () {

  console.log("hello this is answer generator");
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'answers' + {questionNum};

  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){

    div.innerHTML = 
      '<div className="field">\
      <div className="control">\
        <label className="checkbox">\
        <label className="label">Answers</label>\
            <input\
              name="terms"\
              type="checkbox"\
              id="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer'+{i}+'"\
              checked={this.state.terms}\
              onChange={this.handleChange}\
            />\
            I agree to the{" "}\
            <a href="https://google.com">terms and conditions</a>\
        </label>\
      </div>';
    document.getElementsByClassName('answersDiv')[0].appendChild(div)
  }
}


function addQuestion () {
  questionNum++;
  console.log(questionNum + "that is the question number");

  var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = "questions" + questionNum;

    div.innerHTML =
        '<div id="questionGroup'+{questionNum}+'">\
        Question '+{questionNum}+'<br />\
        <input type="text" name="question'+{questionNum}+'"/><br />\
        Answers<br />\
        Check the box(es) for the correct answer(s).<br />\
        <input type="checkbox" name="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer1Box" />\
        <label for="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer1"><input type="text" name="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer1"/></label><br />\
        <input type="checkbox" name="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer2Box" id= />\
        <label for="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer2"><input type="text" name="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer2"/></label><br />\
        <input type="checkbox" name="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer3Box"  />\
        <label for="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer3"><input type="text" name="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer3"/></label><br />\
        <input type="checkbox" name="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer4Box"  />\
        <label for="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer4"><input type="text" name="question'+{questionNum}+'Answer4"/></label><br />\
        </div>';

      document.getElementsByClassName('questions')[0].appendChild(div)


}


export default App;
```

There's a few things to just ignore in here, i just wasn't sure how much info you needed. So the issue is that I get an error when I call my `answersGenerator` function in my `render` function. Here's the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.answersGenerator is not a function` Here's the small piece where that is

```
            <div className="answersDiv">
            <label className="label">Answers</label>
              <div className="field">
                <div className="control">
                  <label className="checkbox">
                      {this.answersGenerator()}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I appreciate the help, if you have any other tips for me other than this issue I am having I am all ears. I am ***very*** new at this, being js and React.

UPDATE: I have edited the `answersDiv` to be just this (I relized it was being called inside a checkbox)

```
        <div className="answersDiv">
        <label className="label">Answers</label>

                  {answersGenerator()}

        </div>
```

I am still getting the same errors though.

Comment: Please, add the error to your question

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving the error because the `answersGenerator()` isn't a method of your class `App`, so, you can't refer to it using `this`. If you want to do on that way, move you function to inside the component, like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    // your component definition etc..
    answersGenerator = () => {
        // your function implementation
    }
    // the rest of your component
}
```

**TIP:**

If you dont want to have to always bind the function, like:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

Declare your method like:

```
handleChange = (event) => { // the implementation }
```

Instead of

```
handleChange(event) { // the implementation }
```

The `() => {}`, known as `arrow function`, does the bind for your.

**EDIT**

You're developing with React, that supports creating `HTML` inside your code. So, you can create an array of answers, then, return a `div` with the answers mapped inside. The `map` will take each `answer` and render inside the `div`. Try to define your method as below:

```
answersGenerator => () {
    console.log("hello this is answer generator");
    var answers = []
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
      answers.push(
        <div className="field">
          <div className="control">
            <label className="checkbox">
               <label className="label">Answers</label>
               <input
                 name="terms"
                 type="checkbox"
                 id=`question${questionNum}Answer${i}`
                 checked={this.state.terms} 
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
               />
               I agree to the{" "}
               <a href="https://google.com">terms and conditions</a>
           </label>
         </div>
       );
    } 
    return <div className=`answer${questionNum}`> {answers.map(answer => answer)} </div>
}
```

Comment: Ok so I took the ``answersGenerator`` function off the bottom there and added it to the ``App`` thing before the ``render`` function like this: (next Comment)

Comment: ``answersGenerator = () => {
        // the stuff the function does
    }``

Comment: And then called it in the render function like this ``{this.answersGenerator()}`` but I still get this error ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined``

Comment: That's because `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't work inside ReactJS. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666140/reactjs-find-elements-by-classname-in-a-react-component/42666506)

Comment: Ah, ok. I've looked over the question linked but I'm not familiar with how ``ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)`` works

Comment: Instead of appending the node, try to return the `div`

Comment: @dorkycam, edited my answer. Tested and working fine here

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like you haven't defined your `answersGenerator()` function within your `App` class.

Thus, `this.answersGenerator()` doesn't exist.

Try just using `answersGenerator()` without the `this`.

Comment: I tried it without the "this" and this is the error I'm getting now ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined``