# Javascript - Whom are the parentNodes?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes, element

I have some confusion over the .parentNode syntax within my code. I reviewed mozilla.org's reference guide which indicates "parentNode is the parent of the current node. The parent of an element is an Element node, a Document node, or a DocumentFragment node." That sounds very black and white but when looking at my code it becomes a bit confusing. I want to eliminate this confusion. Please assist.

Here is my simple
[Codepen Link of HTML and .JS code](https://codepen.io/kevin-orara/pen/RwKvjJz) in question.

Question about audio.parentNode

```
 if(audio) {
audio.currentTime = 0;
const parent = audio.parentNode;
parent.classList.add('active');
```

Who is the the parent of the audio element? I look at other parts of code. On the .JS code below... Is the parent the div element, the className="drum-pad", or perhaps the id={`drum-${text}`}?

```
 <div className="drum-pad" onClick={this.playSound} id={`drum-${text}`}>
    {text}
    <audio ref={this.audio} src={audio} className="clip" id={text} />
  </div>
```

...perhaps its here in the HTML code? Is the parent of the audio element the id which is "drum-machine"?

```
<div id="drum-machine" class="container"></div>
```

Same question about parent.parentNode.

```
const display = parent.parentNode;
display.querySelector('h1').innerText = `${id} is in Effect`;
audio.play();
```

Although I have an idea of the concept behind .parentNode I am not 100% positive in identifying the true child/parent relationship here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just log it in the handler and see for yourself? The parent of the `<audio>` is the `<div>`, the JSX is pretty clear

Comment: @CertainPerformance, are you talking about checking in the console log?

Comment: Yes, logging things when you don't understand something is an essential part of debugging

Comment: `Is the parent the div element, the className="drum-pad", or perhaps the id={drum-${text}}?` ~ the `parentNode` is the `DIV` - the `ID` and `class` are attributes of the parentNode

Answer (score 1):

parentNode refers to the parent element that enclose the target. A simple example:

```
    <div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3"></div>
        <div id="div4"></div>
        <div id="div5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The parentNode of div3/div4/div5 will be div2.
The parentNode of div2 will be div1.

For the Null result you get. I assume you have a typo in the html where

```
<audio ref={this.audio} src={audio} className="clip" id={text} />
```

The attribute for class should be "class" and not "className"

Comment: This is good visual example. Regarding the Null result and usage of className versus class. I am using className as it is utilized within the FreeCodeCamp example here https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/MJyNMd.  I believe you need to use className since the code is in JSX.

Comment: @KevinOrara Owh my bad, didnt notice the JSX thing. I'm not familiar with JSX, but you may try this [Find Elements by className](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666140/reactjs-find-elements-by-classname-in-a-react-component).

Comment: update: I think you can use either `class` or `className`. I've seen people do it either way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code but it returned Null.

```
 let x = document.querySelector('.clip');
    console.log(x.parentNode);
```

I'll check for better code and research on why Null is the correct answer. As a neewbie I will have to get comfortable with debugging. That said, thanks to CertainPerformance and Professor Abronsius for immediate answers plus reminder of parentNode attributes.